# Pointing SLS files to salt directory

Tags: salt-stack

I'm a little confused on using `file_roots`. Currently we setup our salt directory in the following way.

`srv/salt/<folder-connected-to-git>`: contains all the folders we want for to use like win (repo / repo-ng), / scripts /states etc... for our salt build. But it doesn't have our binaries folder (holds the installers for programs).

The master config file uses the following:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/<folder-connected-to-git>
```

So when setting up SLS package installers we would use `salt://` to point to the base folder. Since the binaries folder is outside that path (in `/srv/salt`), I gave the absolute path (ie. `/srv/salt/binaries`). It seems that when running it, salt doesn't recognize this path as an absolute path (maybe its looking for it on the minion instead).

Is there a way to point to directory outside of base. If not, I could change my `file_roots` to:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/
  prod:
    - /srv/salt/<git-folder>
```

But then, would salt look for the repo (to cache to the minion) inside `/srv/salt/` instead of `/srv/salt/<git-folder>`? Could I change what `salt://` points to without changing `file_roots`?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [built in fileserver](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/file_server/) that works together with `salt '*' cp.get_file` or `salt '*' cp.get_dir`. To use this with `file_roots`, you might want to create a separate environment for the binaries.

I am not sure, if it is intended to be used like that. Especially the `file_roots` environments. But I recently learned, that environments are made as flexible as possible, to enable you to use them for whatever you might need them.

You might want to have a look at [gitfs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html) - which allows you to *mount* git repositories into your state tree. This would make the environment unnecessary. We use this approach for formulas.

We currently solve this with a private network and a webserver that makes larger files available to all minions inside of this network. This works quite well, as all our minions are connected to this private network. Running such a network forces you to keep an eye on securing the minions and the masters communication inside of this network. We use local firewalls on all connected minions to achieve this.